# typo3 double quotes in hash __trustedProperties 'The HMAC of the form could not be validated.'

Tags: typo3-11.x, typo3-form

thank you for your support.

I created a form with select options. The fields are filled with arrays provided with the settings variable.

The field in __trustedProperties quoted with the "-sign. This results in "{" as hash.

[__trustedProperties]" value="{"newRfichip":{"id":1,"status":1,"location":1,"personid":1}}2ec7e718db7f0844040e31baaa69a8452a650302" />

Normaly there should be & quot; instead the "-sign.
[__trustedProperties]" value="{& quot;newRfichip& quot;:{& quot;id& quot;:1,& quot;status& quot;:1,& quot;location& quot;:1,& quot;personid& quot;:1}}2ec7e718db7f0844040e31baaa69a8452a650302" />

I get always an exception 'The HMAC of the form could not be validated.'

I'm grateful for every hint, how i can solve this problem

**FormFields.html**

```html
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
<label for="id">
    <f:translate key="tx_bbaorfichip_domain_model_rfichip.id" />
</label><br />
    <f:form.textfield property="id" id="id" /><br />
<br\>
<f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>
<f:debug>{__trustedProperties}</f:debug>
<br\>
<label for="status">
    <f:translate key="tx_bbaorfichip_domain_model_rfichip.status" />
</label><br />
    <f:form.select   property="status" id="status" 
        options="{settings.stati}"
        value="4"
        optionValueField="status"
        optionLabelField="status" />
<br />
<label for="location">
    <f:translate key="tx_bbaorfichip_domain_model_rfichip.location" />
</label><br />
    <f:form.select   property="location" id="location" 
        options="{settings.location}"
        value="4"
        optionValueField="location"
        optionLabelField="location" />
<br />
<label for="personid">
    <f:translate key="tx_bbaorfichip_domain_model_rfichip.personid" />
</label><br />
    <f:form.select   property="personid" id="personid" 
        options="{settings.personid}"
        optionValueField="personid"
        optionLabelField="personid" />
<br />
</html>
```

Comment: I found a hack for mine problem.

Comment: I found a hack for mine problem.
I replace the double quot with single qute in serializeAndHashFormFieldArray  
`       $serializedFormFieldArray = json_encode($formFieldArray);  
         $serializedFormFieldArray = str_replace( '"', "'", $serializedFormFieldArray );  
        ...` 
And switch it back in initializePropertyMappingConfigurationFromRequest  
`...
$serializedTrustedProperties = str_replace( "'", '"', $serializedTrustedProperties );  
$trustedProperties = json_decode($serializedTrustedProperties, true);